# http.request timeout callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout

currently I used the following code to handle the timeout:

```js
var request = http.request(options);

request.setTimeout(30000, function(){
  //when timeout, this callback will be called
});


 request.on('error', function(e){
     //on error when request, this callback will be called
 });
```

The problem is, when the remove server has a slow response and timeout, sometimes the timeout callback will be called, and sometimes **both timeout callback and error callback will be called** (the error inside the error callback is ECONNRESET - connection reset)

If the code call the both callback function, it will break my code's logic, how to I guarantee that only 1 callback will be called for timeout cases? Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way using a counter variable:

```
function onProblem(e) {
  if (onProblem.count > 0)
    return;

  ++onProblem.count;

  if (e) {
    // it was an error
  }
}
onProblem.count = 0;

var request = http.request(options);
request.setTimeout(30000, onProblem);
request.on('error', onProblem);
```

Comment: this tricks works, thanks.
I found that even the clientRequest fired on('error', function(e)) callback, there is a possibilities that it fires on('response', function(response)) callback altogether, therefore it need to lock that callback too